# Screen sharing and screen control on android and iOS using WebRTC

Tags: mobile, webrtc, screensharing

I've to share a mobile screen and display it on a browser using WebRTC. I then have to take control of the mobile screen.

I've researched this and know I can share a screen browser to browser using chrome(with extension) or firefox(after certain flags are set). Some information I've read suggests that screen sharing on mobile is not possible and then another article said it was but I think they meant be sharing through the chrome browser on a mobile.

Some of the the information and posts I read are dating back to 2013/2015/2016 and I wondered if there is any new information on this?

Is screen sharing on mobile devices(android or iOS) possible using webrtc now?

is screen control on mobile devices possible?

Thanks Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I also investigated this topic a few days ago and it seems to me we are on the verge of the next step and the technology hasn't totally settled yet. Screencapture is mostly working with (very) up-to-date browsers and (still) an extension or some kind of white-listing. I could not find any kind of hint that a "remote control" mechanisms are part of webrtc and the getUserMedia implementations. Unfortunately.

ICE seems to work fine for most scenarios (if you don't mind waiting a minute) and Tickled ICE adresses the problem in an interesting way.

Mobile is very confusing indeed as the market is even more heterogeneous.

Maybe we should open a wiki or a chat channel or whatnot they habe nowadays on stackoverflow :-) I think I will have to read about this "community wiki" checkbox down there...

The most promising thing I could find was
https://inthelocus.com/
Still trying it out in different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for that information and link. If I get anymore information on the subject, I’ll put it up here. Andrea

Answer (score 0):

[*This might not be an answer...*] I was on the same topic and then I noticed there's an existing tool (SDK) to serve the similar purpose: https://cobrowse.io. It works good in both the demo video and the simulator web page. Yet I'm not sure if it utilises WebRTC...

Comment: It does not utilise WebRTC, it uses an image, which is somehow updated in realtime.